# Backend Design: System requires both ElasticSearch and MySQL. In which scenario we fetch data from MySQL or ElasticSearch?

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, relational-database, elasticsearch

So, one of the backend system, having 5 resource types (tables) and some foreign keys as well, requires full text support for two of the tables.

Also, for some use-cases, we require inner-joins for some GET requests (depending on user-query).

What I wanted to understand is, for GET requests should we only rely on ElasticSearch, or depending on use-cases we should decide which data-source to pick?

Also, what should we do if user sends a query that requires both full-text-search and inner-joins?

Example:
Models -

```
Product(id, title, description, brand_id)
Brand(id, name)
```

- There can be paginated queries on products and brands -- MySQL works.
- There can be paginated queries on products with brand_id as filter --
  MySQL with where clause works.
- There can be paginated queries on products where user also asks for corresponding brand_name -- MySQL with inner-join works.
- There can be full text search on brand name, product title or description -- ElasticSearch suffices.

The problem occurs, or what I'm confused with is what do I do when the user wants full-text search on product title/description with brand_name of the product?

- Option 1: Get everything from ElasticSearch
- Option 2: Get a list of product.ids from ElasticSearch and then query MySQL
- Option 3: Asynchronously fetch from ElasticSearch and MySQL

Problems I see with each of the approaches:

- Option 1: Are joins even possible in ElasticSearch? Or do we index product with brand_name? If we do the latter, then is it possible to update brand_name in all product documents if a brand updates it's name in MySQL, using LogStash?
- Option 2: Won't this end up being two queries running one after the other? One to fetch the list of product.ids from ES, and then the corresponding join-view from MySQL for those ids? Is this a good approach?
- Option 3: If we fetch asynchronously, how will we manage pagination?

Comment: I recently had to think about a similar problem. I concluded that ES is just an *index* like in a book, where first you search the index, then you lookup the page. So I guess I'd go with option 2, but if that looks overkill... have you considered using the [full text search features of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: @bigstones yup considered MySQL as well, might not work for us with growing requirements. Thanks for the reply (& opinion)!